# News WebPart in SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint-news, news-webpart

I have added a News web part to my SharePoint online site, and I am using the Hub News layout to show the news. For some reason, the fourth news post shows in a weird style. Please see the attached photo.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you post screenshot of your configuration of the news webpart? From the screenshot it is very hard to identify the issue, Can you please elaborate more on your question.

Comment: Does that news page have banner image in the page title or you have used plain page header?

Comment: all the four News having the same configuration.

Comment: Based on the configuration, it appears that the news is sourced from the hub site. Therefore, all the news site pages are likely located within the hub site collection. Have you checked there?

Comment: Thanks for your message, however we don't have hub site in our environment.